# how to plot different colors in a same line in R

Tags: r, plot

I am a new R user. I would like to ask for how to plot different colors in a same line in R.

[image]

Actually, I have already plot a graph, and I would like to change different color in different x-axis. If I would like to change a blue line to replace black line after x-axis 800(800-9xx) and remain black line before x-axis 800. How can I do that?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Your question is a little opaque, but my suggestion would be to use two lines.

Comment: Sorry about that. By the way, can I use `col=ifelse(xxxxxx)` to change it?

Comment: No. Use multiple lines

Comment: Thanks for answering. One more questions, If I have 2 date such as
`1Date: 2010-10-10, 2010-10-11, 2010-10-12`
`2Date: 2010-10-13, 2010-10-14, 2010-10-15`
Can I plot the 1Date first, and plot the 2Date after 1Date in a same graph?
Plot these two Date together.

Comment: It looks like `ifelse` may work, though you will have to figure out the logic: `plot(1:10,1:10, col=ifelse(1:10 < 5, "red", "green"))`.

Comment: Imo: It may work, but I add `type="l"` change it to a line, It will be being a straight red line.

Comment: `library(ggplot2); df <- data.frame(vals = rnorm(100));
ggplot(df, aes(x = seq_along(vals), y = vals, color = I(ifelse(seq_along(vals) > 50, "Blue", "Black")))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1));`

Comment: If your data frame has a factor column indicating where the color should be different, you could use something like the code from @JasonAizkalns,  replacing the `ggplot` call with `ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color=your_factor_column_name)) + geom_line()`.  In this case `x` and `y` are just place holders for columns you would plot.